# How to retrieve the contact from a map?

Tags: apex, map, wrapper-class

**Wrapper Class:**

```
public class WrapperFilter1 {

    public Id employeeId1{get;set;}
    public String employeeName1{get;set;}
    public String employeeEmail1{get;set;}

    public String skillName1{get;set;}
    public String proficiency1{get;set;}
    public String yearOfExp1{get;set;}
    public String skillType1{get;set;}

    public String trainingName1{get;set;}

    public String certificationName1{get;set;}  

}
```

**Controller:**

```
Map<Id, WrapperFilter1> wrapperMap1 = new Map<Id,WrapperFilter1>(); //map
List<WrapperFilter1> wFilter1 = new List<WrapperFilter1>(); //list of wrapper

for (Employee_Skills__c eSkills : skillList) {

   if (wrapperMap1.containsKey(eSkills.Employee_ID__c)) { //check if map contains an id
       wFilter1.add(wrapperMap1.get(eSkills.Employee_ID__c)); //add the map to the list
   }

   WrapperFilter1 wrapper = new WrapperFilter1(); //new wrapper class
   wrapper.employeeId1 = eSkills.Employee_Id__c;
   wrapper.employeeName1 = eSkills.Employee_ID__r.Name;
   wrapper.employeeEmail1 = eSkills.Employee_ID__r.Email;
   wrapper.skillName1 = eSkills.Skill_ID__r.Name;
   wrapper.proficiency1 = eSkills.Proficiency__c;
   wrapper.yearOfExp1 = eSkills.Year_of_Experience__c;
   wrapper.skillType1 = eSkills.Skill_Type__c;

   wrapperMap1.put(wrapper.employeeId1, wrapper);

   wFilter1.add(wrapper); //add the new wrapper class to list of wrapper class

}


for(Contact con: contList){

**<<<<HOW CAN WE RETRIEVE THE CONTACT FROM THE WRAPPERMAP1 HERE?>>>>**

}
```

QUESTION: We're planning to create a search engine with 5 filters, then we decided to create a wrapper class per filter. We retrieve the list of Employee_Skills__c records and put it on the wrapper class. Our problem is how can we retrieve the contact from the wrappermap1?

Comment: Does your map contains Contact as Value/key? I don't think there is any Contact in the map

Comment: It doesn't have but the employeeId1 contains the Employee_ID__c which is also the ID of the Contact.

Comment: @lone, did RCS answer your question?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment mentioned above `Employee_ID__c` is nothing but the Contact Id. Try to use the below code to retrieve the map values.

```
Map<Id, WrapperFilter1> wrapperMap1 = new Map<Id,WrapperFilter1>(); //map
List<WrapperFilter1> wFilter1 = new List<WrapperFilter1>(); //list of wrapper

for (Employee_Skills__c eSkills : skillList) {

   if (wrapperMap1.containsKey(eSkills.Employee_ID__c)) { //check if map contains an id
       wFilter1.add(wrapperMap1.get(eSkills.Employee_ID__c)); //add the map to the list
   }

   WrapperFilter1 wrapper = new WrapperFilter1(); //new wrapper class
   wrapper.employeeId1 = eSkills.Employee_Id__c;
   wrapper.employeeName1 = eSkills.Employee_ID__r.Name;
   wrapper.employeeEmail1 = eSkills.Employee_ID__r.Email;
   wrapper.skillName1 = eSkills.Skill_ID__r.Name;
   wrapper.proficiency1 = eSkills.Proficiency__c;
   wrapper.yearOfExp1 = eSkills.Year_of_Experience__c;
   wrapper.skillType1 = eSkills.Skill_Type__c;

   wrapperMap1.put(wrapper.employeeId1, wrapper);

   wFilter1.add(wrapper); //add the new wrapper class to list of wrapper class

}


for(Contact con: contList){
    WrapperFilter1 wrapperObj = wrapperMap1.get(con.Id);
}
```